# Adding a KeyListener to multiple JTextFields using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jtextfield, keylistener

I have 32 textfields to whom I want to add a KeyListener which ensures that only numerical input is taken. I am using the same function declaration for the keyTyped() function for all textfields but when I assign it to an array of JTextFields (txtPw) in a for loop, it does not take any input at all.

```
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
        txtsPw[i].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
        {
               public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
               {
                  if (!(Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar()) || (e.getKeyChar()=='.')))
                      e.consume();
                  else if (e.getKeyChar()=='.' && txtsPw[i].getText().length() - txtsPw[i].getText().replace(".", "").length() > 0)
                      e.consume();
                  else if (txtsPw[i].getText().length() > 7)
                      e.consume();
               }
        });
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Does this code compile?  I get "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" error.

Answer (score 0):

you could make two `JTextFields` that one is editable and one isn't, so when a user inputs the numbers and sends it to the other text box, you can check if it's a number or not. If you want i can present an example, although, I'd like you to try and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    createKeyListener(txtsPw[i]);
}

private void createKeyListener(TextView tv)
{
    tv.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
           public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
           {
              if (!(Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar()) || (e.getKeyChar()=='.')))
                  e.consume();
              else if (e.getKeyChar()=='.' && tv.getText().length() - tv.getText().replace(".", "").length() > 0)
                  e.consume();
              else if (tv.getText().length() > 7)
                  e.consume();
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is more readable, but what did you change ? (And I doubt it compiles because of conditions in your `else if` as `txtsPw[i]` is no more known in your `createKeyListener` method)

Comment: I extracted the `addKeyListener` to a private method, and call it on concrete views; That should avoid `i` having to be final, so should technically work for all views in case the OP's filter worked in the first place.

Good catch on the `else if`

Comment: You should have written this in your answer besides your code. It could help some slow-mind guys like me :). (And it is always more pleasant/helpful).